# How to get the image location using image id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of images in a page.

```
<a href="http://imagelocation" id="image-selected[0]"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://imagelocation" id="image-selected[1]"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://imagelocation" id="image-selected[2]"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
```

Now I need to get the imagelocation in a jquery variable if I click on any of the images. 
How can I get that?

I tried this and not working.

```
$('#image-selected').click(function(){
  alert($('#image-selected').attr('href'));
})
```

Comment: Your jQuery selector is incorrect. `$('#image-selected')` won't target any elements because there are no elements with that ID. I would suggest adding a class to each image container(same class for each) and using that as your selector. You will also want to change the second line to `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have better to use a common class instead...
But regarding your issue, you could use the startsWith attribute selector:

```
$('[id^=image-selected]').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

Comment: @user1012181your fiddle does not have the jQuery library loaded. Here is a working Fiddle using the above answer: http://jsfiddle.net/aLrtf4wu/

Comment: The funny thing is, in my application, it is not working. No errors. I have the jquery and everything is there. But no alert.

Comment: Maybe you try to bind event before elements are available in DOM. Set you code inside document ready handler `$(function(){...});` where `...` is the code in this answer. Maybe you are using dynamic elements, then delegate event, e.g, `$(document).on('click', '[id^=image-selected]', function(){alert(this.href);});` One last thing, you should have to prevent default behaviour of anchor click, depending expected behaviour

Comment: These images are appearing when I fill a textbox. So based on the textbox input, the API request is made and images are created. I put your answer below the function for the API image request and display. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vdfrmtxa/6/ (code wont' work. Just wanted to show you the Js file)

Comment: So you should delegate event to `#images` level, it would be: `$("#images").on('click', '[id^=image-select]', function(){alert(this.href);});`

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

**html:**

```
<a href="http://imagelocation" class="image-selected"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://imagelocation" class="image-selected"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://imagelocation" class="image-selected"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.image-selected').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy! You want the element that initiated the event :)

```
$('img').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
}
```

It's better to use a class rather than an id, as an id is used as a unique identifier

Answer (score -1):

Just Update if you need Image location of link :

```
$('[id^=image-selected]').click(function(){
  alert('img',$this).attr('src');
});
```

I will suggest use class to trigger jquery function on all of the links like below :

```
<a href="http://imagelocation" class="imgLink" id="image-selected[0]"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://imagelocation" class="imgLink" id="image-selected[1]"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
<a href="http://imagelocation" class="imgLink" id="image-selected[2]"><img src="http://imagelocation" alt=""></a>
```

Now, your jquery can be as easy as :

```
$('.imgLink').click(function(){
  alert('img',$this).attr('src');
});
```